# Can't js function 'alter' or 'confirm' in crosswalk

Tags: android, html, crosswalk

Crosswalk 16.45.421.19

I use crosswalk as a library in my project ,but when I call js function 'alert' in my html,there are some errors.

```
05-17 16:12:27.136: E/chromium(2559): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(172)]                         Not implemented reached in virtual void          xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
05-17 16:12:27.251: I/chromium(2559): [INFO:CONSOLE(376)] "exec() is calledSmartdotTelephone.deviceInfo", source: file:///android_asset/www/common/mau/MDHAdapter.js (376)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/ResourceType(2559): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:319)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:405)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:382)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkUIClientInternal.onJsAlert(XWalkUIClientInternal.java:390)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkUIClientInternal.onJavascriptModalDialog(XWalkUIClientInternal.java:166)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkContentsClientBridge.handleJsAlert(XWalkContentsClientBridge.java:715)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5423)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
05-17 16:12:27.271: W/System.err(2559):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
05-17 16:12:27.271: A/chromium(2559): [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
```

I see the source of crosswalk,in XWalkUIClientInternal.java

```
@XWalkAPI
public boolean onJsAlert(XWalkViewInternal view, String url, String message,
        XWalkJavascriptResultInternal result) {
    final XWalkJavascriptResultInternal fResult = result;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.js_alert_title))
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(android.R.string.ok),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    fResult.confirm();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    fResult.cancel();
                }
            });
    mDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    mDialog.show();
    return false;
}
```

R.string.js_alert_title is the resource ID for crosswalk, it is not local resource ID in my project,why crosswalk don't use dynamic loading local resource for alert function, and how to resovle?

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk works well in calling js 'alert' function.
For example, there is a js_java_interaction.html in assets folder:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function alertMessage(message) {
        alert(message)
    }
</script>
Java-Javascript Interaction In Android
</html>
```

Load the html in your activity:
`mXWalkView.load("file:///android_asset/js_java_interaction.html", null);`

And after the loading, please use evaluateJavascript() API:

```
call = "javascript:alertMessage(\"" + "content" + "\")";
xwalkview.evaluateJavascript(call, null);
```